# Heroku cant find PyNaCl in my discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py, cloud-hosting

```
2020-07-25T01:12:27.370500+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371718+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371770+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371771+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371774+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "bot.py", line 63, in on_voice_state_update
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371774+00:00 app[worker.1]:     voice = await channel.connect()
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371776+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1076, in connect
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371777+00:00 app[worker.1]:     voice = VoiceClient(state=state, timeout=timeout, channel=self)
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371794+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 91, in __init__
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371795+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise RuntimeError("PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice")
2020-07-25T01:12:27.371828+00:00 app[worker.1]: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

my discord bot works fine and do music stuffs when I start it with my editor. but when heroku tries to do it, I get this error. what do I do? I installed the PyNaCl thing via pip. i dont know how to add it to my code because my code worked fine without pynacl and working fine with it. I cant import it in my code(module not found). I have no idea what it is tho.

Comment: Add `PyNaCl` to your requirements.txt file

Comment: I tried and still getting the same error